# On the units of a residue ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an intergal domain, $K$ its field of fractions, $p$ a prime ideal of $A$. If $A$ is a valuation ring of $K$ ( i.e. for any $y\in K, y≠0$, one of $y\in A$ or $y^{-1}\in A$ must holds, for more details, see Atiyah and Macdonald, chapter 5), then is it true that any unit of the ring $A/p$ is of the form $x+p$, where $x$ is a unit of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is whether for $A$ a valuation ring, the ring surjection $A \twoheadrightarrow A/p$ induces a surjection on the groups of units $A^\times \to (A/p)^\times$. This is true, because a valuation ring is local. If $m$ is the maximal ideal of $A$, then $m/p$ is the unique maximal ideal of $A/p$, so if $x + p \in (A/p)^\times$ is a unit, then $x + p \not \in m/p \implies x \not \in m$, so $x \in A^\times$ is a unit.

Note that neither $p$ being prime, nor $A$ being a domain, is necessary, and it is true more generally that if $R$ is semilocal (i.e. has only finitely many maximal ideals) and $I$ is any proper $R$-ideal, then the surjection $R \twoheadrightarrow R/I$ induces a surjection on unit groups $R^\times \twoheadrightarrow (R/I)^\times$. For more details, see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/153526/44201).

Comment: Thank you very much, a beautiful answer!

Comment: @Lao-tzu: You're welcome! By the way, do you want to mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: Of course, but I don't know how to do this (as always), can you give some hint?

Comment: Underneath the vote arrow, you should see a checkmark (currently gray). If you click it once, it should turn green, which means that you've accepted it

Comment: Rather simple but I'd never knew how to do it!

Comment: Now you know! I would also suggest going back and accepting old answers that you've received and found useful - it's generally a nice gesture